# Google +SignIn Issue

Tags: javascript, google-plus, google-oauth

I am doing google + sign in , i am able to do everthing, and it is working mostely fine,
But my problem is that for the first time it is asking me to enter user name and password, but when i log out from the app, and then again clciks on sign in button then it is directly signing me to the account, without asking user name and password. I want that it will ask again user name and password, Please can any one help me. You can also check the demo.
[CheckDemo Here](http://wheresgus.com/signindemo/)

Comment: You can check the demo ,it is using google client libraray.

Answer (score 0):

The given demo works good. After i logout and click signin it ask for the password(is this you actually need?).
If you are login in gmail, it does not ask for password and get login automatically since the google(gmail, google plus) use same authentication details(email and password).

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/ I want this type of behavior, use sign in with google

Comment: S/He wants Google to ask for password everytime s/he tries to sign in with Google I guess.

Comment: yes @Picrofo Software , after logging out like gmail, i want that it will ask user to enter user name or password.